# Improving connection in a specific node in tracert?

Tags: networking

I've been having huge internet problems recently, with huge fluctuations in connection throughout the day - to the extent of it being nearly unusable at certain times, and better past a certain time such as 1 AM - that I really want to fix. I ran a tracert to a server for a game I normally play, but also for google, and noticed a pattern.

```
  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.0.1
  2   118 ms   134 ms   136 ms  adsl-98-81-166-1.hsv.bellsouth.net [98.81.166.1]
  3   117 ms   134 ms   152 ms  70.159.223.95
  4    28 ms    26 ms    23 ms  12.81.99.62
  5    40 ms    23 ms    22 ms  12.81.99.28  
  6    22 ms    22 ms    22 ms  12.83.24.60
  7    25 ms    22 ms    21 ms  12.81.36.2
  8    26 ms    23 ms    23 ms  12.81.104.142
  9    22 ms    21 ms    21 ms  12.81.16.55
  10   23 ms    23 ms    23 ms  74.175.192.86
  11   40 ms    38 ms    39 ms  cr1.attga.ip.att.net [12.122.141.186]
  12   42 ms    39 ms    38 ms  cr2.dlstx.ip.att.net [12.122.2.110]
  13   38 ms    44 ms    46 ms  12.122.85.197
  14   38 ms    38 ms    37 ms  206.121.120.30
  15   48 ms    48 ms    47 ms  104.160.134.35
  16   47 ms    46 ms    49 ms  ae35-br02.chi01.riotdirect.net [104.160.159.24]
```

This is what I would consider the average tracert to the program, but at the times in which I mentioned the internet works just fine, lines 2 and 3 would have numbers similarly low to the others like 20ms. Can this be seen as a problem with the physical connection to this area? These tests were ran without programs using internet in the background, so it should be correct.

If it isn't a physical problem with the connection, what are the methods I can take to try to improve lines 2 and 3 specifically? It seems to be the culprit that is hurting my internet connection greatly.

Comment: If it takes 118+ ms to reach 98.81.166.1 then how can it take 28ms (and lower) to go to {98.81.166.1 and then to 70.159.223.95 and then 12.81.99.62}.  I'm wondering if the issue isn't with both 98.81.166.1 and 70.159.223.95, but if the issue was just temporary (i.e., if you sent a Traceroute packet every 2 seconds, maybe it was a 6 second issue).  If issue is truly related to time of day, and your network doesn't do anything at such specific times, you may wish to open ISP trouble ticket to have them monitor/investigate from their end.  I also suggest re-Tracert to see if results consistent.

Comment: Only your ISP can fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on comments a little:

Considering your connection to your home gateway is a stable(across 3 pings) one we'll assume for now its not your network causing the problem but outside it. That being true you cannot fix it other than changing ISP or sometimes using a VPN to bypass a chokepoint which only works in very specific circumstances.

Secondly the tracert is only a very rough tool, it uses ICMP which network equipment knows is "dummy" traffic and can treat with a low priority. The slow results likely means bells RAS/router is prioritizing the fwding of traffic vs responding to requests to itself. Means nothing about your game performance.

Lastly, Riot uses a complex CDN with encapsulation to route traffic to their server farms in a way that some hops between you and the game host may be invisible to you.